# Why is there a preference for seemingly inconsistent punctuation of abbreviations like US, UK, EU?

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

Today, the [WSJ reports](https://www.wsj.com/articles/eus-barnier-seeks-clarity-from-u-k-over-brexit-divorce-bill-1500550926): "EU, U.K. Make Progress in Brexit Talks but Clash Over Divorce Bill." So, it appears as though they have no uniform/simple rule for such abbreviations' punctuation.

I've looked into this before and found that the Wikipedia-preferred abbreviations are U.S., UK, EU. Oxford Living Dictionaries has US, UK, EU. Encyclopædia Britannica has U.S., U.K., EU. Merriam-Webster has U.S./US, UK, EU.

So, it appears that several styles do not require a simple (style-internal) consistency for such abbreviations. **What is the idea behind this preferred (seeming) inconsistency?**

Comment: I'm not sure lack of standardization can be explained. Usually explanations are reserved for conscious, principled approaches to standardize things.

Comment: Exactly. They are not intentionally inconsistent, but no conscious coordination was undertaken to make them consistent.

Comment: @DanBron I'm allowing for an answer that provides an explanation that does have standardisation, but that is more subtle than a simple/expected one.

Comment: This just feels like general inconsistency, rather than anything deeper.

Comment: How and when should these publications get together and decide? What if they can't agree to agree? When should the WSJ care about anything written in Wikipedia? That leaves the WSJ and Oxford. What is the Encyclopædia Britannicam? Why should anyone expect them to agree? There is no preference to disagree.

Comment: @Clare It could be that these publications each have their own consistent rules (which may differ between publications). I'm not asking why they don't agree amongst _each other_. I'm asking why some of them _seem_ to be inconsistent _internally_. (Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A6dia_Britannica.)

Comment: Okay, there may be a spelling inconsistency but the uses might not be inconsistent based on other criteria. Otherwise is there a requirement that these works be consistent?

Comment: @Clare It is the (possible) other criteria that I am asking for (implicitly). There is no 'requirement' for _internal_ consistency, but if you look at "EU, U.K. Make Progress [...]" you might agree that that seems weird in such close proximity, possibly requiring an explanation beyond reference to the applicable style manual's specific directives.

Comment: There's no link here to the original.  Given the on-line, quick publication of many stories, errors often appear early and are corrected later.

Comment: Does the EU specify how it wants to be abbreviated in English? This could be the cause of the inconsistency.

Comment: Please clarify your question by spelling out what WSJ stands for.  The reader should not have to do a web search to find out. Or is this your preference for (seeming) inconsistency (whatever that might mean)?

Comment: @PeterShor That might very well be it. "[U]se either the full form
(European Union) or the abbreviation ‘EU’." And "As a general principle, acronyms and initialisms do not have a full stop between the capitals." From: http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-000500.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly because actual usage is inconsistent.

### Wikipedia

Wikipedia does NOT prefer mixing "U.S." (with periods) with "UK" or "EU" according to their [style guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Abbreviations#Acronyms):

> Some American editors prefer to use "U.S." However, use a consistent style within the same article; use "US" in articles with other national abbreviations, e.g. "UK" or "UAE".

### Oxford Living Dictionaries

The actual entries are consistent, but [elsewhere](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-abbreviations) they note that American English uses periods in some abbreviations:

> 1. In both American and British English, if you are using initial letters to represent words, you don’t normally need to put a full stop/period after:
>
>    > NBC
> 2. In American English, however, it is common to use a full stop/period as an alternative style for certain abbreviations, in particular:
>
>    > USA or U.S.A.
>    >     US or U.S.

### Merriam-Webster

They explain the whole "US" vs. "U.S." thing [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/how-should-you-write-it-united-states-u-s-or-us):

> **Question**
>   When to use "US" and when to use "U.S."?  – Mianxiu, China
>
> **Answer**
>   This is an excellent question and a hard one to answer, because the rules are changing all the time. You will see examples of this abbreviation written both ways, with periods (U.S.), and without (US). To make matters worse, some well-respected style guides recommend the first style, and others prefer the second. Finally, the choice partly depends on whether U.S. is functioning as a noun or as an adjective.

### Encyclopædia Britannica

I don't know what style guide (if any) they use, but I'd say their choices are valid:

- It is common to use "U.S." (with periods)
- "U.K." (with periods) is the older and more traditional spelling (e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=2eRDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP7&dq="uk"+united+kingdom)).
- EU has always been spelled without periods. It's not really an option to spell it with periods.

---

It's also interesting to note what spelling they use on their websites:

- [USA.gov](https://www.usa.gov/) uses "U.S." (with periods)
- [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/) uses "UK" (no periods)
- [Europa.eu](https://europa.eu/european-union/index_en) uses "EU" (no periods)

---

Here are some links to what different style guides recommend:

- [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/abbreviations/#Q12)
- [MLA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/11/)
- [University of Oxford](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf)

Comment: So maybe it's always EU because that's what the European Union wants (the same reason we've changed the spelling of Kolkata, Myanmar, Beijing, and Sri Lanka.)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Clare How doesn't it? The OP asked why the styles weren't internally consistent, and I answered.

Answer (score -4):

There's no justification of that kind of inconsistency within that piece of writing from the  Wall Street Journal. That's just mediocre and sloppy writing. You either use X.Y or XY within a piece, but not both. Initialism without punctuation is more prevalent in American writing.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/initialisms

> For example, the forms US and U.S. are both acceptable, **as long as one or the other is used consistently within a piece of writing**.

Comment: Without checking, I'm reasonably confident that this is not mediocre/sloppy writing, but rather sticking to the WSJ style manual. Edit: sort of confirmed by looking in "The Wall Street Journal Guide to Business Style and Usage"

Comment: @Keepthesemind That guide is only useful for the particular publisher to set a general and arbitrary style guide for themselves within the context of business.  I couldn't "sort of confirm" by looking in a manual that is not open to the public. If the manual actually states such a thing then please provide an answer with the proper source to explain why they are ok with that kind of mediocre and sloppy writing.

Comment: You can use [Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=3mjxg9iNAQUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+Wall+Street+Journal+Guide+to+Business+Style+and+Usage&hl=en) to find "The Wall Street Journal Guide to Business Style and Usage", and then search (in the box on the left side) for US, UK, EU. As far as I can see, the manual does not provide a general or specific 'why'. (Search 'abbreviation'.)

Comment: @Keepthesemind By all means provide an answer using that source. I couldn't find anything in that link that would suggest mixing both forms of initialism within a piece of writing  as actually acceptable for the Wall Street Journal or anything else. So, if you have the answer then please share.